# AntiXSS JavaScriptEncode gets HTML encoded?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, antixsslibrary

I've just started using AntiXSS (4.3.0), mostly to use `@Encoder.JavaScriptEncode` as described [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/preventing-javascript-encoding-xss-attacks-in-asp-net-mvc).

I installed AntiXSS from Nuget, then added `encoderType="Microsoft.Security.Application.AntiXssEncoder, AntiXssLibrary"` to `<httpRuntime` in my Web.config.

In my view, I have the following line (within `<script>` tags):

```
var userId = @Encoder.JavaScriptEncode(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

Which I would expect to output

```
var userId = 'user-id';
```

but instead outputs:

```
var userId = &#39;user-id&#39;;
```

I assume this is happening because Razor is trying to sanitize the HTML, and thus encoding the singe quotes as `&#39;`.

The solution then would be to just wrap it in `Html.Raw()`, but in the [post I was following](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/preventing-javascript-encoding-xss-attacks-in-asp-net-mvc) he never does that (instead wrapping the whole thing in single quotes within the Javascript).

My question is - are you supposed to need to call `@Html.Raw(Encoder.JavaScriptEncode(data))`, or is there something wrong with my setup?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assumption about razor encoding is correct. I'd also say the [post you were following](http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/preventing-javascript-encoding-xss-attacks-in-asp-net-mvc) is also correct (I may be wrong, I haven't read the entire post though).

Instead of

```
var userId = @Encoder.JavaScriptEncode(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

try

```
var userId = '@Encoder.JavaScriptEncode(User.Identity.GetUserId(), emitQuotes: false)';
//optionally surround with '' if your userId needs to be a string
```

or just

```
var userId = @Encoder.JavaScriptEncode(User.Identity.GetUserId(), emitQuotes: false);
// Visual Studio gives you a red squiggly syntax error after the semi-colon though.
// From your example, if it is a number, then no quotes are required
```

or go ahead with `Html.Raw()` like

```
var userId = Html.Raw(@Encoder.JavaScriptEncode(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

*Opionated:* I prefer emitQuotes: false because that option is there, and because it eliminates the needs for another function call `Html.Raw()`. The default for **emitQuotes** is true. *Are you missing the **emitQuotes** parameter or is that intentional?*

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to make sure, seeing as though it's rather weird.

Also, I'm using Identities 2.0, which defaults to a string ID (which is why I'm trying to get it in quotes)